# How to search word/terms on a webview

Tags: android, webview, find

I made a button, when clicked it does a search inside of a webview. It works but I dont know how to implement the next/previous and how to remove the highlight of the words. I realized that I can't remove it =/

the button:

```
 testeSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                search("T");

            }
        });
    }
```

and the method is:

```
  public void search(String query) {
        wv.findAllAsync(query);

    }
```

How can I do next or previous and remove the highlight of the letters?

thx.

Answer (score 0):

## Removing Highlighting

To remove the highlighting, call `webView.findAllAsync(null)`

## Moving to Next Search Result

To move forward to the next search term, use `webView.findNext(true)`

## Moving to Previous Search Result

To move to the previous search term, use `webView.findNext(false)`